# How can I use site visitor's current location coordinates as starting point to show Google direction map on my site?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to show Google direction map on my site. Suppose I have saved some address/coordinates in the Admin-end as the destination address/coordinates. Let us think a user tries to access the website from front-end. I have picked user's current location coordinates through JavaScript, now I have to use this coordinates (which is I have accessed through JavaScript) as the starting point of the route map and the coordinates (which I have saved in the Admin-end) as the ending point of the route map.

How can I pass the user's current location coordinates (which I have accessed through JavaScript) as the starting point coordinates of the map?

If it is not possible through JavaScript then please tell me some other way to do this.

Here is the JavaScript code that I am using to show Google Map.

```
    <script>
function initMap() {
    var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
    var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 14,
      center: {lat: 26.8653676, lng: 80.9440718}
    });
    directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
document.getElementById('mode').addEventListener('change', function() {
  calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
});
 } 
var final_latitude=0;var final_longitude=0;

 if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError,{maximumAge:0});
            } else { 
                alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";);
            }
            function showPosition(position) {
                var lati=position.coords.latitude;
                final_latitude=lati;
                var longi=position.coords.longitude;
                final_longitude=longi;
                calculateAndDisplayRoute();
            }
            function showError(error) {
                switch(error.code) {
                    case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
                        alert("User denied the request for Geolocation.");
                        break;
                    case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
                        alert("Location information is unavailable.");
                        break;
                    case error.TIMEOUT:
                        alert("The request to get user location timed out.");
                        break;
                    case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
                        alert("An unknown error occurred.");
                        break;
                }
            }   
  function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
    var selectedMode = document.getElementById('mode').value;
    var start = {lat: final_latitude, lng: final_longitude};  //This is not working
    var end = new google.maps.LatLng(26.8466937, 80.946166);
    directionsService.route({
      //origin: {lat: 37.77, lng: -122.447},  // Haight.
      //destination: {lat: 37.768, lng: -122.511},  // Ocean Beach.
      origin: start,
      destination: end,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode]
    }, function(response, status) {
      if (status == 'OK') {
        directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
      } else {
        window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
      }
    });
  }
</script>
<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=my_API_Key&callback=initMap">
    </script>
```

In the above code I need to pass the visitor's current location coordinates in `var start = {lat: final_latitude, lng: final_longitude};` but it is not working.

Comment: have you alert start lat,lng? is it giving some value?

Comment: what is your method of passing the variables?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're probably attempting to utilize your start lat/long before they've been set.

1. Your function definition in showPosition doesn't match the function below, you should. Not necessarily a problem, but it makes your code more problematic.
2. Your code on line 18 has a problematic semicolon

Try this:

```
function initMap() {
var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 14,
    center: {
        lat: 26.8653676,
        lng: 80.9440718
    }
});
directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
document.getElementById('mode').addEventListener('change', function() 

{
        calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
    });
}
var final_latitude = 0;
var final_longitude = 0;
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, showError, {
        maximumAge: 0
    });
} else {
    alert("Geolocation is not supported by this browser.");
}
function showPosition(position) {
    var lati = position.coords.latitude;
    final_latitude = lati;
    var longi = position.coords.longitude;
    final_longitude = longi;
    calculateAndDisplayRoute();
}
function showError(error) {
    switch (error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            alert("User denied the request for Geolocation.");
            break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
            alert("Location information is unavailable.");
            break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
            alert("The request to get user location timed out.");
            break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
            alert("An unknown error occurred.");
            break;
    }
}
function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
    var selectedMode = document.getElementById('mode').value;
    var start = new google.maps.LatLng(final_latitude, final_longitude);
    var end = new google.maps.LatLng(26.8466937, 80.946166);
    directionsService.route({
        //origin: {lat: 37.77, lng: -122.447},  // Haight.
        //destination: {lat: 37.768, lng: -122.511},  // Ocean Beach.
        origin: start,
        destination: end,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode]
    }, function(response, status) {
        if (status == 'OK') {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        } else {
            window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
        }
    });
}
```

Additionally - in my experience, browser location can take a while (8+ seconds). Are you waiting long enough for the callback to run? Try adding breakpoints in chrome and seeing when it executes.

Comment: Hi JonLuca,
Thank you very much for the solution, I have tried your code but it was not working so I have made some changes in your code and I got my solution. In line 33 instead of `calculateAndDisplayRoute();` I have used all of the `initMap()` code and it worked.